# Trying to create quantity x cost with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a merchandise page where I have put the items into separate tables.  I want to have it so that when someone selects a quantity, it will display the appropriate price in the field below.  Here's the HTML so far:

```html
<table border="1" id="tshirtTable" style="float:left">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Burundi T-Shirt</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><img src="https://rlv.zcache.com/burundi_t_shirt-re5f84ff8b0724bbda7582389e5816a6f_k2g1o_324.jpg" alt="Burundi T-shirt"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="qty">Quantity</td>
    <td>
      <select id="tshirt">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="price">Price</td>
    <td><input type="text" disabled="true"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm pretty new to JS so not sure how to have it calculate the price, depending on which quantity is selected.  Guessing I'll have to set the price somewhere, but not exactly sure how to get started on it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There appears to be a lot for you to figure out. Like how to accept answers when people take their time to try and help you. http://stackoverflow.com/users/7617740/conor

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not terribly sure what you're getting at?

Comment: It is good etiquette to upvote answers that have been helpful and accept those that solved your problem. Regarding your issue at hand: You need to listen to the 'change' event of your <select> and set the value of the price input to the new price. In order to compute the new price, you need the selection value and the basic price which should be available somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I have always been very polite and appreciative when responding to people who have given me answers; I haven't used Stack a massive amount of times so wasn't aware of these things so thanks for letting me know.

Thanks for the suggestion on the issue, I'll have a look and see if I can get that to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored your code. In my example, we have list of products. It doesn't really matter, you can have here one product or as many as you want. For learning purposes it's better do handle table of items.

First of all we won't be using `disabled` attribute but `readonly`. It's is very important, because `disabled` key-value won't be send to the server. If you want to block the input from changing use `readonly`. Secondly you don't need to pass `=true` value to your attribute.

```
<input type="text" disabled="true"> // bad
<input type="text" readonly> // ok
```

Another thing is that attribute `id` is unique per `document` and we can have only one. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be
>   unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
>   when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
>   (with CSS).

No jQuery in my example, you should learn pure javascript first.

To calc, we must change type of our values. Reading them from inputs, their type is `String`, we must convert them to `Number`. In our case we use `parseInt()` function. It's better to use `parseFloat()`, when we expect floating point number.

Read my comments to have better understanding what is going on. If you have any confusion make sure to ask.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tshirtTable');

table.addEventListener("change", function(e) {

  // If we are not changing these elements we quit
  if (e.target.name !== 'quantity' && e.target.name !== 'each-price') {
    return;
  }

  // Let's check what is id of our element
  // We store our id in <tr id="..."
  // To access tr, we must find tr by using .closest function
  var tr = e.target.closest('tr'); 
  
  var productId = tr.id;
  
  
  var quantityValue = tr.querySelector('.quantity').value;
  var eachPriceValue = tr.querySelector('.each-price').value;
  var totalPriceValue = tr.querySelector('.total-price').value;
  
  // Here is important part, we must parse values as type Number, because currently they are type String
  
  
  tr.querySelector('.total-price').value = ( parseInt(quantityValue) * parseInt(eachPriceValue)).toFixed(2);

});
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tshirtTable" style="float:left">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price / Each</th>
      <th>Total Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="1">
        <td>Burundi T-Shirt</td>
        <td><select class="quantity" name="quantity">
          <option value="0" selected>0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="each-price" type="text" name="each-price" value="15"></td>
      <td><input class="total-price" name="total-price" type="text" readonly></td>
      </tr>
            <tr id="2">
        <td>Burundi Skirt</td>
        <td><select class="quantity" name="quantity">
          <option value="0" selected>0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="each-price" type="text" name="each-price" value="25"></td>
      <td><input class="total-price" name="total-price" type="text" readonly></td>
      </tr>
            <tr id="3">
        <td>Burundi Mask</td>
        <td><select class="quantity" name="quantity">
          <option value="0" selected>0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="each-price" type="text" name="each-price" value="30"></td>
      <td><input class="total-price" name="total-price" type="text" readonly></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: perfect, thank you very much.  It seems to be very clear and I am just inputting it now - will get back to you if any issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add function which have to be call on document ready or as pure javascript document.onload()
Then you have to define a variable name for the price, 
Then you have to get the value of your (#tishirt) and multiply it with the price get the result as a value for your text input in which the price display 
Here is the script

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
document.onload=function(){
document.getElementById(#tishirt).onchange=function(){
var price=100 ;//only example price
var total=price*document.getElementById(#tishirt).value;
if (total>0){
document.getElementById(#total).value=total;
}
};
};
</script>
```

Don't forget to add id to your text box (#total)